# Query to display initials of Full Names

Tags: sql

I have a column "Customername" from my Customer table that includes both first and last name eg. "John Smith".

How do I get it to display this column as the name as initialisation of first name followed by a dot and then the last name eg. "J. Smith" for the whole column?

Comment: What about names like "John C. Dvorak" or "Leonardo da Vinci"? You can do this with a lot of messing around in SQL using string functions, but honestly this is a hundred times easier in the application layer if you have one.

Comment: Same opinion as @tadman, but you could also define a **FUNCTION** in your db engine.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Answer (score 1):

For MySQL you can do this:

```
 Select CONCAT(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(fullname, 1, INSTR(fullname, ' ') - 1), 1, 1), '. ',
 SUBSTRING (fullname, INSTR(fullname, ' ') + 1, char_length(fullname)))
 from Persons;
```

Explanation:

```
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING(fullname, 1, INSTR(fullname, ' ') - 1), 1, 1
```

This will return the first letter of 'First Name'. You can also do this:

```
SUBSTRING(fullname, 1, 1)
```

which will give you the first letter of the full name.

Concatenate it with ". " and the last name to get your string.

As mentioned in comments, its much easier to have a function. Also, it is a good idea to have multiple columns for first and last name and time to normalize.

I used the following:

```
CREATE TABLE Persons (
    PersonID int,
    fullname varchar(255)
);

insert into Persons values (10, "Suresh Yadav");
insert into Persons values (20, "Jane Smith");
```

Answer (score -1):

I created a function for this to find initials dynamically, I hope this helps.

- Checking unwanted duplicates in the full name
- Checking left or right spaces and trimming them
- Then find initials and use them with dot and space (Firstname and Lastname initials: F. L) You can modify this part as you wish

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetInitials 
( @text varchar(max))

RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)

AS
BEGIN

DECLARE  @Result NVARCHAR(MAX)
while charindex('  ',@text)>0

 set @text=TRIM(replace(@text,'  ',' '))

 SELECT @Result = STRING_AGG(UPPER(LEFT(value,1)),N'. ')  FROM STRING_SPLIT (@text, N' ') 
 RETURN @Result
 END
```

Unit Test

```
Declare @fullName varchar(100)
set @fullName = '  Mary  Jane Sarah Naomi  Patterson  '

SELECT dbo._GetInitials(@fullName)

Declare @fullName varchar(100)
set @fullName = 'Mary Jane'

SELECT dbo._GetInitials(@fullName)
```